# How to import different classes based on the chosen configuration in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I have a configuration file Config.py with one class Config. This class has one variable to be set e.g., model (model=1 or model=2). If model=1, i would like to import relevant classes from folder model1 (e.g., model1/X.py). The same for model=2, but from flder model2 (model2/X.py).

The code is structred like this

```
lib/
  Main.py
  Config.py
  model1/
    X.py
  model2/
    X.py
```

Main.py: the main class to start with. We import Config.py as

```
from Config import Config

if Config.model ==1: from model1.X import X
elif Config.model ==2: from model2.X import X
```

The solution used in Main.py works, but i am looking for more efficient solution, especially that i have many different classes. Thus, it is boring to add the condition on top of every python file. Furthermore,i might extend the code by adding model3, model4, etc.  Is there any easy way to implement my dea without having the conditions on every file?.

Comment: Could you abstract the importing process to a separate file? Like `import_modules.py` which contains your `if` statements and then just import this into all your files?

Comment: I tried something similar, but did not work. assume model1, has A.py, B.py, C.py, X.py. in main i only need to import X.py, but in another file i need B.py. But with condition solution, in each file i can specify which files i can import (not all files, which will cause a prblem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importlib` for [dynamic imports](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

```
from importlib import import_module
from Config import Config
model_name = 'model' + str(Config.model) + '.X'

X = getattr(import_module(model_name), 'X')
```

I would advise against it though. Sometimes the verbose solution is better. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: how this differentiate between model1 and model2 to be used. Also, do i have to do this in every python file where i need to import classes that exist in both model1 and model2?. To be clear, I called here model1 (but it can be any name), same for model2.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the dunder import

```py
module = __import__(modulename)
```

this stores the imported model in the model variable for later use. modelname needs to be a correct name of a library or importable file/folder